# How do i get the list of Reviewers for a pull request using Github api?

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-for-mac

I need the list of reviewers for a PR, and the [Review Requests API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/review_requests/) present in Github only provides me the requested reviewers which becomes empty once the reviewers have accepted their invitations. I also tried the [Reviews API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/) to get all reviews and then get unique users, but that seems to be only for users who enter one and not for those who have accepted the request review invitation and never posted a review.

Comment: This helped me to figure it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391344/automatically-merge-verified-and-tested-github-pull-requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically merge verified and tested GitHub Pull Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391344/automatically-merge-verified-and-tested-github-pull-requests)

Comment: hi @JesonDias it might be late, but did you find the solution (to get all reviewers) using API calls.

Comment: Even I am looking for the same solution as this forum question from yesterday, has anyone got a working solution or reference to guide on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just went through this problem with the following solution.

According to [GitHub's documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/review_requests/#list-review-requests):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:pull_number/requested_reviewers
```

> Pull request authors and repository owners and collaborators can
>   request a pull request review from anyone with write access to the
>   repository. Each requested reviewer will receive a notification asking
>   them to review the pull request.

Test Request:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/roliveiravictor/demo-rust-learning/pulls/1/requested_reviewers
```

Response:

```
{
    "users": [],
    "teams": []
}
```

Since nobody is settle on this public test repo, of course it's empty. Remember, **they need to have write access on your repository**. This worked pretty well on my private project.

Comment: `/requested_reviewers` is about pending review requests. Once a person approves, comments, or rejects, it disappears from the list. 
Thus, it is a perfectly valid situation to have this list empty while there are might be 5 different people who left their feedback.

Comment: I wish they wrote that information to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The way to get other reviewers is
`https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/reviews` 
You will get all actual reviews, and `state` will show is it `APPROVED` or `CHANGES_REQUESTED`. And each review also has a `user`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use this in an automation like a GitHub Action, if this is the case, simply use this: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-github-pull-request-reviews

If not, you can simply fetch the reviews from the GitHub API like so:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{AUTHOR}/{REPOSITORY}/pulls/{PULL_REQUEST_ID}/reviews
```

E.g: https://api.github.com/repos/bitcoin/bitcoin/pulls/29413/reviews

---

Only things to worry about then is the rate limits: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/rate-limits-for-the-rest-api

| Plan | Requests per hour |
| --- | --- |
| Unauthenticated | 50 |
| Personal | 5000 |
| Enterprise | 15000 |