# How to get the list of reviewers in GitHub

Tags: javascript, github

On the Pull Request pane, we can see a list of pull requests, and a picture of who is assigned to the review. At this company, the person assigned is the person writing the code, not the person doing the review.

If I click on a pull request, I can see there is both a Reviewers and Assignees list.

I want to get the assignee.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/company/project/pulls/123
```

When I query the above, it returns me with something that is nearly perfect... The return object has `requested_reviewers` which should have been perfect... The problem is, it sometimes returns a result and other times it does not. What I mean is that it is consistent, but if I have 3 items to be reviewed, and say 2 have reviewers, the return will only indicate that 1 of the 3 has reviewers.

My question appears identical to [How do i get the list of Reviewers for a pull request using Github api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965073/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-reviewers-for-a-pull-request-using-github-api) but, whilst there is no answer, the poster has claimed there is a post which answers the question, but that is about web hooks.

I'm trying to simply query the API direct to get the list of reviewers for a given ticket.

My code executes fine, and I don't feel there is anything wrong with it.

```
function success(d) {
    //do something on ajax callback
}

function fail() {
    alert("Failed... Big boom boom");
}

function start(ticket) {
    ajaxGet(success, fail, "https://api.github.com/repos/company/project/pulls/" + ticket, _token);
}

function ajaxGet(ajaxSuccessCallback, ajaxFailCallback, url, auth) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": auth,
        },
        success: function (d) {
            ajaxSuccessCallback(d);
        },
        error: function (d) {
            ajaxFailCallback(d);
        }
    });
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**

When I saw reviewer, I mean the person who appears in this list on the Pull requests page

[image]

Comment: `sometimes returns a result and other times it does not` for the same given ID?

Comment: It's always consistent with an ID. So, as per my description, if I have 3 rows (pull requests). Let's assume when I click on the first entry, I see there is a reviewer (or multiple). When I click on the second row, I see there is a reviewer (or multiple). And when I click on the last, I see there are none. This means, that 2 of the 3 have reviewer(s) assigned. However, it will always return that only 1 has a reviewer assigned

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate [endpoint for getting a list of requested reviewers](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/review_requests/#list-review-requests):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/requested_reviewers
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Is this requested or people who *are* reviewers

Comment: `reviewers`, at least in terms of GitHub, are owners of a very specific `Pull Request Review` resource (see: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/).  Are you after "participants"?  That is, anyone that is assigned/review is requested of them/commented/?

Comment: Hi. I have updated my post with a screen shot. I hope this helps?