# How to get all reviewers using GitHub REST API?

Tags: api, rest, github, github-api, pull-request

When I make REST GET to my repository by this path

`https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/requested_reviewers`

I get not all reviewers assigned to PR.

I receive only those who did nothing with review. For example, I have PR with reviewers **A, B, C** and **D**.

After creation PR **A** requested some changes, **C** approved pull request, **B** and **D** did nothing. If I get `requested_reviewers` three will be only **B** and **D**, but I need all of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i get the list of Reviewers for a pull request using Github api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965073/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-reviewers-for-a-pull-request-using-github-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get **A** and **C** is
`https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/reviews` 
You will get all active reviews, and `state` will show is it `APPROVED` or `CHANGES_REQUESTED`